# Periodic AJAX Call doesn't update my server status

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a problem with my code. AJAX call obtains info from JSON array while entering page and after refresh and puts it as desired in my HTML code, but the problem is, that  doesn't do it in set loop (30s). Here's my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function status_ts3(){
    $.ajax({
            url : '/lib/ts3_stats.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (response) {
                $('#ts3-status').replaceWith(response['server_status']);
                $('#ts3-number-online').replaceWith(response['online_number']);
            },
            error : function() {
               $('#ts3-status').replaceWith('<span class="server-offline">Offline</span>');
               $('#ts3-number-online').replaceWith('<span class="online-number-ts3">0/0</span>');
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(status_ts3, 30000);
            }   
    })});
```

**PHP:**

```
$ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://@xxx/?server_port=xxx");
$status = $ts3->getProperty("virtualserver_status");
$count = $ts3->getProperty("virtualserver_clientsonline") - $ts3->getProperty("virtualserver_queryclientsonline");
$max = $ts3->getProperty("virtualserver_maxclients");
$servers_ts3='<span class="server-online">' . ucfirst($status) .'</span>';
$online_number_ts3 = '<span class="online-number-ts3">' . $count . '/' . $max . '</span>';
$ajax = array(
    'server_status' => $servers_ts3,
    'online_number' => $online_number_ts3,
);
echo json_encode($ajax);
```

So the question is, why it doesn't work? Did i miss something or misunderstood? I'm half-newbie so I don't really know, would appreciate all help.

Comment: Anything in a developers console?

Comment: Well, I've got no errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly (I've noticed word "Periodic" in the title) you would like to call this AJAX call every 30s. If so you need to use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` as:

> setTimeout(function, milliseconds)
>   Executes a function, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds.
>
> setInterval(function, milliseconds)
>   Same as setTimeout(), but repeats the execution of the function continuously.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

If that is the case you should first setup the polling and then define the function to call the AJAX like:

```
setInterval(status_ts3, 30000);

$(function status_ts3(){
  $.ajax({
    ...
  })
});
```

And remove the `complete` callback form AJAX handling function.